# Executing a perl script using PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, perl, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to execute a perl script at the click of a button in an application(Oracle Apex). The script I can place in the DB host which the app interacts with. In apex i can execute PL/SQL code. Is there a way by which I can execute the perl script using PL/SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call Perl modules from PL/SQL, Oracle Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583602/how-do-i-call-perl-modules-from-pl-sql-oracle-forms)

Answer (score 1):

You can call Java from PL/SQL. With Java you can execute anything from the command line.

Random Example:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

public class Adjuster {
  public static void raiseSalary (int empNo, float percent)
  throws SQLException { 
    Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
    String sql = "UPDATE emp SET sal = sal * ? WHERE empno = ?";
    try {
      PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pstmt.setFloat(1, (1 + percent / 100));
      pstmt.setInt(2, empNo);
      pstmt.executeUpdate();
      pstmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
  }
}

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE raise_salary (empno NUMBER, pct NUMBER)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Adjuster.raiseSalary(int, float)';
```

Manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chfive.htm